# Setting ApplicationBarButton.IconUri with icon from Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am working on windows phone application in which i need to change ApplicationBarButton icon dinamically, for example to show current date like in default Windows Phone Calendar app. Regarding to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431806%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), we can use only png images previously added to solution and reference to them with relative Uri.

It is not a problem for me to generate correct png image ([this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638675%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and using ToolStack C# PNG Writer Library) and save it to isolated storage, but when i'm initializing AppBarButton with absolute Uri to this image and trying to add it to ApplicationBar, my app throws ArgumentException.

Am i doing something wrong or i just have to draw 366 icons and add them to my project? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to generate your `ApplicationBarButton` icon? have you confirmed the image is being written to `IsolatedStorage`?

Comment: @NeilTurner, I'm pretty sure and additionally checked this with Isolated Storage Explorer. Here is [link](https://bitbucket.org/ArtemFlotsky/wp-applicationbarbuttoniconfromiso) to repository with sample project